Не отображается камера на сайте
Делаю сайт, в котором в том числе будет присутствовать сканер QR.
Вылезает ошибка, что картинка якобы имеет ширину 0. Я же хочу вообще на весь экран созерцать изображение с камеры. Подскажите куда копать, пробовал на разных устройствах


// Функция для инициализации сканера
function startScanner() {
  const qrReader = new Html5Qrcode("qr-reader");
  const config = {
    fps: 10, // Частота кадров
    qrbox: {
      width: 250,
      height: 250
    } // Размер квадрата для сканирования
  };
  qrReader.start({
      facingMode: "environment"
    }, // Камера устройства
    config, (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
      console.log("QR Code detected: ", decodedText);
      alert(`QR Code detected: $ {
          decodedText
        }
        `);
      showScreen('screen4'); // Переход на экран 4 после сканирования
    }, (errorMessage) => {
      console.error("Ошибка сканирования:", errorMessage); // Обработка ошибок
    }
  ).catch(err => {
    console.error("Ошибка запуска сканера:", err);
    alert("Не удалось запустить сканер. Проверьте доступ к камере.");
  });
}
<div id="scanner-container" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="qr-reader" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  <div class="scanner-box"></div>
  <!-- Квадрат для сканирования -->
</div>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
